# SQLite3 Time Problem 11 getting selected before 2

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a SQLite database that has a time field set as a text type. And it contains values like `11:30 PM, 2:30 PM, etc` and I need to select time and date by date & time ASC. I use the following query `SELECT * FROM schedule ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC LIMIT 50`

But the problem is I get values such as 11:30PM before 2:30PM

How can I avoid this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are storing in human readable format a value that should be meaningful for a machine.  Since sqlite doesn't have a native time type, you'll have to make do with the next nearest approximation, which is a numeric type.  You could store both date and time as a single number, for instance as [seconds since January 1st, 1970](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), and then [format those values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) for presentation to users at the last moment.